# How do I prevent ")" adding a space?

Tags: windows-7, cmd

The line

```
(FOR %F IN ("Q:\Playlists\A 1*.m3u") DO @echo "%~nF")| sed -E "s/.*/x&y/"
```

produces

```
x"A 1 T Soft FC La melodia de nuestro adios" y
```

rather than

```
x"A 1 T Soft FC La melodia de nuestro adios"y
```

as expected.

How do I prevent ")" adding this space?

Comment: Ash Burlaczenko, I removed your added batch-file tag. This question is not about a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way the command you type is being parsed and executed. Each side of the pipe is executed inside a separate instance of `cmd.exe`. Those instances do not execute the code you have typed as you have typed it, but a slightly different version that has been reinterpreted by the parser. In this step the aditional space has been included ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950927/2861476) you can found a deeper analysis by dbenham)

We can not avoid the way the parser do its work, but we can generate a command where the added spaces do not affect the output

```
cmd /q /c "(for %f in ("Q:\Playlists\A 1*.m3u") do echo("%~nf")"| sed -E "s/.*/x&y/"
```

Comment: Oh dear. I had not realised how borked CMD truly is. Thanks. FTR, the minimal-change fix based on yours is: cmd /q /c "(FOR %F IN ("Q:\Playlists\A 1*.m3u") DO @echo "%~nF")"| sed -E "s/.*/x&y/"

Comment: @ChrisJJ, the `/q` switch in the call to `cmd` means to start with echo off, so, you don't need the `@` prefix.

Comment: Thanks. So the minimal-change fix becomes: cmd /c "(FOR %F IN ("Q:\Playlists\A 1*.m3u") DO @echo "%~nF")"| sed -E "s/.*/x&y/" . Does your /q have an advantage over @ ?

Comment: @ChrisJJ, in this case, no advantage, there is only one command that needs to be not echoed. I was just pointing to the redundance in the final command.

Answer (score 0):

```
(@FOR %F IN ("u:\sourcedir\A 1*.m3u") DO @ECHO x"%~nF"y)
```

worked perfectly well for me. No idea why you're using `sed`...(I changed the directory to suit my system)

Comment: Yup, that works for me too... but is no answer :) sed gives greater flexibility.