# Windows cmd echo / pipe is adding extra space at the end - how to trim it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe, echo

I'm working on a script that executes a command line application which requires user input at runtime (sadly command line arguments are not provided).

So my first attempt looked like this:

```
@echo off
(echo N
echo %~dp0%SomeOther\Directory\
echo Y)|call "%~dp0%SomeDirectory\SadSoftware.exe"
```

At first glance it looked like it worked pretty well, but as it turned out it didn't. After investigation I found out that the directory I was passing to the software contained extra space at the end, which resulted in some problems.

I looked around for a while and found out following question:
[echo is adding space when used with a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948824/echo-is-adding-space-when-used-with-a-pipe) .

This explained what is going on, but didn't really help me solve my problem (I'm not too familiar with batch programming).

At the moment I "kind of solved" my problem with an ugly workaround:

```
echo N> omg.txt
echo %~dp0%SomeOther\Directory\>> omg.txt
echo Y>> omg.txt

"%~dp0%SomeDirectory\SadSoftware.exe"<omg.txt

del omg.txt
```

This solution works, but I'm less than happy with it. Is there some prettier way? Or even uglier way, but without temporary file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution1: Linefeeds**

You can use a linefeed to avoid the spaces.
The `rem.` is required to avoid problems with the injected `&` by cmd.exe

```
SET LF=^


REM ** The two empts lines are required for the new line **

(
echo line1%%LF%%rem.
echo line2%%LF%%rem.
echo line3%%LF%%rem.
) | sort
```

When a block is piped the cmd.exe will rebuild the block by building a single line combined with ampersands between each command.

```
(
echo line1
echo line2
) | sort
```

Will be converted to

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" (<space>echo line1<space>&<space>echo line2<space>)"
```

So the linefeed trick results in a line like

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" ( echo line1%LF%rem. & echo line2%LF%rem. )"
```

And this expands to

```
( echo line1
rem. & echo line2
rem. )
```

**Solution2: Escaped ampersands**
You can also use directly ampersands, but they need to be escaped, else the spaces are injected anyway.
The last `rem.` is to avoid a space after the last echo

```
( 
    echo Line1^&echo Line2^&echo Line3^&rem. 
) | more
```

**Solution3: Create a single command**
@MCND Mentioned the trick to use directly the form:

```
cmd /q /c"(echo line1&echo line2&echo line3)" | sort
```

This works, as the parser only sees the `cmd` command, the rest is handled as parameters for this single command.
Therefore there aren't any problems with spaces.
Or with the linefeeds it looks like

```
cmd /q /c"(echo line1%%LF%%echo line2%%LF%%echo line3)"| (sort > out.txt)
```

And then you can modify it also to

```
cmd /q /c^"(echo line1%%LF%%^
echo line2%%LF%%^
echo line3)^"| (sort > out.txt)
```

Comment: Just for completion, maybe you could include `cmd /q /c"(echo line1)&(echo line2)&(echo line3)"|more`

Comment: Thanks!
I've used the second solution and it works like a charm. ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I've used Solution2 in this way (new lines are not allowed in comments therefore "<crlf>" is a new line here):
`(<crlf>
echo b^& ^<crlf>
echo a^& ^<crlf>
rem.<crlf>
) | sort`
so you don't have to put everything in one line.