# Trailing space in parenthesized output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to sort user-input line without using output to file, just in memory, and save the result to variable:

**"b" "c" "a" -> "a" "b" "c"**

But the code I use produces the trailing space on each chunc:

**"b" "c" "a" -> "a"[space][space]"b"[space][space]"c"[space]**

For removing trailing space and building resulting variable I use some **:HelpProc** calling.

1. Ho to avoid trailing spaces without deleting them manually?
2. Maybe there is other way for building the result line, without using procedure call?

```
@echo off

echo Copy and paste this: "b&b" "a!a" "d%%d" "e e" "c^c"
echo/
<nul set /p="Enter string: "
set /p string=
echo/

set "SortedLine="
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('(for %%y in (%string%^) do @echo %%y^)^|sort') do (
    echo Extracted: [%%x]
    set "word=%%x"
    call :HelpProc
)
echo/
:: Remove first space
set SortedLine=%SortedLine:~1%
echo Sorted Line: [%SortedLine%]

echo/ & pause & exit /b

:HelpProc
    :: Remove trailing space
    set word=%word:~0,-1%
    set SortedLine=%SortedLine% %word%
exit /b
```

Comment: The cause of the trailing space on each line can be more easily seen on creating a batch file with just the command line `(for %%y in ("b&b" "a!a" "d%%d" "e e" "c^c") do @echo %%y)|%SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /O SortedList.txt` and running this batch file from within a command prompt window to see also the the command line after parsing it by `cmd.exe` before execution. The output command line after parsing is: `(for %y in ("b&b" "a!a" "d%d" "e e" "c^c") do @echo %y )  | C:\WINDOWS\System32\sort.exe /O SortedList.txt`. There is a space inserted left to last `)` which is output by `echo`.

Comment: I could not yet find a solution for preventing the output of a trailing space by `echo` caused by the space inserted by `cmd.exe` left to closing round bracket of the command block of which output is redirected to `sort`.

Comment: The space isn't there when you redirect the `for` loop to a file. It isn't there, when you sort that file - neither by `sort file.tmp` nor by `type file.tmp|sort`. So it's not the `echo` or `for` loop. It's the combination of `for`, pipe, and `sort, which adds the space. Very strange and unexpected.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948824/echo-is-adding-space-when-used-with-a-pipe) (no satisfying solution though)